# Postgresql - Renumber columns

Tags: postgresql

I need to renumber the rows of my database. After I delete some rows I have to **renumber** certain column. How can I do that using `postgresql`?

**UPDATE**:
For example:
I have a table like this:

```
ac_n_circ     name

1               x 
2               y
8               c
15              b
```

And I want to renumber this table like this:

```
ac_n_circ     name

1               x 
2               y
3               c
4               b
```

Is there any algorithm or something like that to do this in posgresql?

Thanks!

Comment: can you be more specific? do the new numbers be in any order? please provide an example of what you have and what you expect to get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Caution:

### This only makes sense if `ac_n_circ` is *NOT* the primary key column.

If you are sure you need this (are you really?), then something like the following should work:

```
with new_numbers as  (
   select row_number() over (order by ac_n_circ) as new_nr,
          ac_n_circ, 
          id
   from foo
) 
update foo
   set ac_n_circ = nn.new_nr
from new_numbers nn 
 where nn.id = foo.id;
```

Alternatively:

```
update foo 
  set ac_n_circ = nn.new_number
from (
   select id, 
          ac_n_circ,
          row_number() over (order by ac_n_circ) as new_number
   from foo
) nn
where nn.id = foo.id;
```

Both statements assume that there is a primary key column named `id`.

Comment: **ac_n_circ is not the primary key** :)